# setTimeout to loop html5 video doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looping a segment from a html5 `<video>` element by calling `setTimeout` on a loop function that calls itself at the end to restart the loop. 
I don't want to use `timeupdate` event to loop the video because it fires too infrequently for the level of precision I need in displaying the looping video segment.

My code runs and does everything as it should, both on mobile and desktop (Please try running the code segment below).

However, when I insert the component into the rest of my application, when viewing the app in a **mobile browser (safari and chrome iOS)**, the video stops looping when I adjust the "Start Time" value using the slider.

Puzzlingly, the video plays and loops correctly when first loading the component. But when you interact with the "Start Time" slider to change the `startTime`, `this.loop` seems to get called once and doesn't fire again.
This makes me suspect that the issue is with the `setTimeout` function.

What is going on? Why is it working correctly by itself (outside of my app, as in the below snippet), but not when it is rendered in the rest of my application?

Could it be related to the fact that my application has a lot of other components and the browser doesn't have as many resources to run the timeOut function as often?

Specifically, what is the behavior of `setTimeout(somefunction, null)` on mobile browsers?

edit: I got it working by setting the timeout delay to be 500ms: `setTimeout(this.loop, 500)`, but I still don't really understand why it's behaving the way it does. It definitely seems to be related to the frequency of the `this.loop()` calls.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    maxDuration: 60,
    startTime: 0,
    duration: 5
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      startTime: props.startTime,
      duration: props.duration,
      videoDuration: 0,
      maxDuration: props.maxDuration,
      maxStartTime: 0
    }
  }

  play = (e) => {
    this.loop()
  }

  loop = () => {
    const startTime = this.state.startTime
    const duration = this.state.duration
    // const currentTime = this.parseValue(this.video.currentTime)
    const currentTime = this.video.currentTime

    if (duration === 0) {
      this.pauseVideo()
    } else {
      this.video.play()
      if (currentTime < startTime) {
        this.video.currentTime = startTime
      } else if (currentTime > startTime + duration) {
        this.video.currentTime = startTime
      }
    }
    this.timeout = setTimeout(this.loop, null)
  }

  pauseVideo = () => {
    this.video.pause()
  }

  parseValue = (value, precision = 1) => {
    return parseFloat(parseFloat(value).toFixed(precision))
  }

  updateDuration = e => {
    const { videoDuration, maxDuration } = this.state
    const duration = Math.min(maxDuration, this.parseValue(e.target.value))

    this.setState({
      duration
    })
  }

  updateStartTime = e => {
    const { duration, videoDuration } = this.state
    const startTime = this.parseValue(e.target.value)
    const maxDuration = Math.min(this.props.maxDuration, this.parseValue(videoDuration - startTime))
    
    this.setState({
      startTime,
      maxDuration,
      duration: Math.min(maxDuration, duration)
    })
  }

  updateVideo = e => {
    this.setState({
      currentTime: this.parseValue(this.video.currentTime, 2)
    })
  }

  handleLoadedMetadata = e => {
    const videoDuration = this.parseValue(e.target.duration)
    const duration  = Math.min(this.state.duration, videoDuration)
    this.setState({
      duration,
      maxStartTime: videoDuration,
      maxDuration: Math.min(this.state.maxDuration, videoDuration),
      videoDuration
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <main>
          <div style={{width: '80%', margin: '0 auto'}}>
            <div>
              {
                this.video ? [
                  `Video length: ${this.video.duration}`, 
                  <br/>,
                  `Time: ${this.state.currentTime}`,
                  <br/>,
                  `Max duration: ${this.state.maxDuration}`
                ] : null
              }
            </div>
            <video width={'100%'} playsInline autoPlay muted loop ref={el => this.video = el} onPlay={this.play} onLoadedMetadata={this.handleLoadedMetadata} onTimeUpdate={this.updateVideo}>
              <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" />
            </video>
            <div>
              Start Time: {this.state.startTime}
              <br/>
              <input style={{width:'100%'}} type="range" onChange={this.updateStartTime} value={this.state.startTime} step={0.1} max={this.state.maxStartTime} />
            </div>
            <div>
              Duration: {this.state.duration}
              <br/>
              <input style={{width:'100%'}} type="range" onChange={this.updateDuration} value={this.state.duration} step={0.1} max={Math.min(this.props.maxDuration, this.state.videoDuration)} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, you may be right with this `Could it be related to the fact that my application has a lot of other components and the browser doesn't have as many resources to run the timeOut function as often?`. Because `setTimeout()` doesn't fire immediately even if the wait time is 0 as it waits for the main thread to get free to execute the callback. Why don't you call the `loop` again at the end of `loop` and add some condition in it to stop the loop whenever you click close button or something.

Comment: `setTimeout(somefunction, null)`, is not the same as `setTimeout(somefunction)`;  omitting the *milliseconds* parameter results in `setTimeout(somefunction, 0)`, which has an entirely different meaning.  The reason that desktop browsers treat `null` and `0` the same in this instance has always been up for debate.

Comment: @Claies noted, but if the browser treats null as 0 in this case, isn't the end result the same when passing null or 0 or omitting the delay param?

Comment: yes, but the question is about **mobile browsers**, which I don't believe behave in that manner.  I would suspect that if you could see the error console in the mobile browser, it would have errors regarding that `null` param.  an easy way to test that would be to use `0` in the function (this is *possibly* why 500ms worked.....)

Comment: I think, setTimeout with a zero delay is a bad idea all together, if you really really need the checks to be super frequent you should at least use requestAnimationFrame. There's no need checking for an update more than once a frame here.